# Probability of getting $n$ consecutive heads in $m$ throws.

Tags: probability

Suppose you have an honest coin and it is flipped $m$ times, what is the possibility of you getting $n$ ($n<m$) consecutive heads?

I tried to solve through the obvious way (suppose $H$= head, $T$ = Tail, $X$= Head or Tail), then we consider the possibilities:

- $\underbrace{H \ldots H}_{n\ \text{times}}\ \underbrace{X \dots X}_{m-n\ \text{times}}$ ;
- $X\ \underbrace{H \ldots H}_{n\ \text{times}}\ \underbrace{X \dots X}_{m-n-1\ \text{times}}$;
- $\vdots$
- $\underbrace{X \ldots X}_{m-n\ \text{times}}\ \underbrace{H \ldots H}_{m\  \text{times}}$;

The problem is, you need to take out the intercessions and then things get complicated...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: it's a little complicated to explain the problem here. In case $H ... H X ... X$ and $X H ... H X X ... X$, it is very easy to solve the problem, we just force the first $X$ of $X H. ... H X ... X$ be a $T$. The problem begins to appear when the $X$ sequence $X... X$ has more than $n$ terms because in this case, you need to ensure that a sequence of $n$ $H$'s does not appear in these $X$'s.

Comment: I am not sure if it is a standard problem...

Comment: Maybe I spoke too soon.  I'll take another look at it, but I don't have time right this moment.

Comment: There is a solution to this exact problem in "Sheldon Ross' Book - A First Course in Probability" 8th edition, 4th chapter, page 148, Example 7d,  (English version).

Comment: You''re right.  It's more complicated than I realized.  I was just thinking that we have to consider cases where we have sequences of more than $n$ heads, but we also have to consider cases where we have multiple non-intersecting sequences of $n$ or more heads.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt.

Since you need only n consecutive heads and don't care about the rest, then the preceeding or/and succeeding outcome has to be tail. It is like arranging children in a row with m spots and n boys sit together .

So, make a block of n H's + T (considering the streak to occur at the beginning) (Case 1).

Case 2 : make a block of T + n H's (at the end).

Case 3 : make a block of T + n H's + T ( in middle - the streak begins and ends somewhere ).

Now N(fav) = No. Of ways of Arrangement(Case 1 + Case 2 + Case 3). N(Total) = m! And P(reqd) = N(fav)/N(total).

Case 1 : after making our block(B), total no. Of spots = (m - n) as follows :

B, X,.....,X ( X = H,T) ( m - n -1 times ) So no. Of ways = (m - n)! · 2(m - n - 1)  [ Since (m-n-1) spots can have two values ]

Case 2 : Same as case 1, same value

Case 3 : after making our block(B), total no. Of spots = (m - n - 1) as follows :

X,...,B,...X ( Total no. Of X's = m - n - 2 but variable on either side ( in case of zero it's just T H...H T X... ) )

So, no. Of ways = (m - n - 1)! · 2(m - n - 2)  [ Since (m-n-2) spots can have two values ]

This gives the answer

Comment: "Since you need only $n$ consecutive heads and don't care about the rest, then the preceding or/and the succeeding outcome has to be tail", Are you sure? For example $H T \underbrace{H ... H}_{n+1\ \text{times}} T H .... H$ is a possibility

Comment: I see the loophole. Thanks